# Since Kafka Streams is now available, is Spark and Akka necessary in the SMACK stack?

Tags: apache-kafka-streams, smack-stack

About to sink my teeth into Kafka Streams with an IoT data ingestion architecture and see a lot of [SMACK stack](http://www.natalinobusa.com/2015/11/why-is-smack-stack-all-rage-lately.html) examples.  However, with [Kafka Streams](https://www.confluent.io/blog/introducing-kafka-streams-stream-processing-made-simple/) now available is Spark and Akka really required (maybe just no Spark)?

Comment: "There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the information you shared this is a pretty broad question, so please don't mind my giving a perhaps overly broad answer by saying "Yes" -- you can replace Spark and Akka with Kafka's Streams API (and including perhaps Kafka's Connect API, too)" for an ingestion architecture.

PS: I think other SO readers would benefit from narrowing down your question, e.g. by being more explicit about what you are trying to achieve and what your various requirements are.